# Sorting a singly linked list - I dont get it

Tags: c, linked-list

I´m looking at example 6.7 from http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html

(Pasted here for convenience)

```
struct list_ele *
sortfun( struct list_ele *list )
{

      int exchange;
      struct list_ele *nextp, *thisp, dummy;

      /*
       * Algorithm is this:
       * Repeatedly scan list.
       * If two list items are out of order,
       * link them in the other way round.
       * Stop if a full pass is made and no
       * exchanges are required.
       * The whole business is confused by
       * working one element behind the
       * first one of interest.
       * This is because of the simple mechanics of
       * linking and unlinking elements.
       */

      dummy.pointer = list;
      do{
              exchange = 0;
              thisp = &dummy;
              while( (nextp = thisp->pointer)
                      && nextp->pointer){
                      if(nextp->data < nextp->pointer->data){
                              /* exchange */
                              exchange = 1;
                              thisp->pointer = nextp->pointer;
                              nextp->pointer =
                                      thisp->pointer->pointer;
                              thisp->pointer->pointer = nextp;
                      }
                      thisp = thisp->pointer;
              }
      }while(exchange);

      return(dummy.pointer);
}
```

I get the basic idea, but I cant really explain whats happening in there. Can someone explain in more depth but in simple manner whats going on in that sort function?

Some questions in general:

- Why is `dummy.pointer = list;` needed? `dummy` is then returned at the end of the function, how come the list is still sorted?
- What does the comment `The whole business is confused by working one element behind the first one of interest.` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dummy` is a local variable that is first set to the start of the list.  The temporary variable `thisp` is set to point to `dummy` and so when it is updated, the contents pointed to by `dummy` are also updated.  Thus, `dummy.pointer` will eventually point to the element that is the new beginning of the sorted list.  `list` will still point the original start of the list, so the value is returned so the head pointer can be updated.

I think what they mean by confusing is that element we are interested in is `nextp`, not the current element (or `thisp`).  That is, we are comparing the next element in the list with the current element, rather than comparing the current one with the previous. I guess that's *confusing*, but I don't really find it so.

Note: this is [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). A better sort algorithm would be [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), with an implementation at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes it clearer what dummy does, especially in conjunction with thisp. What I find hard to understand: why is the do/while construct needed? In my naive idea I would just iterate through the list and do the swapping…

Comment: @Max consider the list c => b => a.  go through the inner loop once and you get b => a => c (swap b with c, swap a with c). You need to continue to go through the list until you don't make any exchanges.  only at that point do you know then entire list is in order.  that's what the outside loop guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm goes through the list look at each list item and the one after it. If they are out of order, they get switched around. The process is then repeated. Eventually there will be nothing out of place and nothing gets switched; at that point all the work is done (as indicated by `exchanged` remaining zero). In other words the last time through the list, nothing gets interchanged.

The dummy is used to keep track of the list itself (in case the first 2 list items ever get switched). It is used (instead of just a simple pointer to the list because it can also serve as a fake first item so that there is something to compare the original first item in the list. It eliminates the need for the special case of the result list's first item being different from the original list's first item.

Work it out on paper for a list of 1, 2, 3, and 4 items. You'll then see how it works. When you work it through, try putting the list in order to start with and running the algorithm. Then interchange 2 items in the list and do it again.

Regarding the comment about the whole business being confused, all it refers to IMHO is the fact that you must keep track of 3 nodes in a singly-linked list in order to swap two of them. If you have items A C B in the list (and the goal is for the list to be A B C), when you swap B and C you must also have access to A - it's 'next node' pointer must get changed from C to B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Doing an example on paper is a good idea. At another look I think the most unintuitive part is the do/while(exchange) why is this needed? Cant I just iterate through the list and swap the values around?

Comment: You can't go through the list just once. In the worst case (i.e., the list is in descending order but you want it sorted into ascending order), it takes many iterations until every item has 'settled' into its final position. Try sorting a list by hand of 5 items (for example), initially ordered in this worst case; you'll see how each iteration successively refines the ordering until the goal is finally achieved.